# Analyzing kmemleak result

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am running kmemleak on one of my modules to find leaks, below is the result after a while.
From the result, what i understand is below address are object/s address in the .ko or .o file.

```
unreferenced object 0xffff8803c9708f10 (size 32):
  comm "resiter_access_i_o", pid 2320, jiffies 4294798486
  hex dump (first 32 bytes):
    d8 8e 70 c9 03 88 ff ff a0 8e 70 c9 03 88 ff ff  ..p.......p.....
    68 8e 70 c9 03 88 ff ff 30 8e 70 c9 03 88 ff ff  h.p.....0.p.....
  backtrace:
    [<ffffffff81516e3e>] kmemleak_alloc+0x5e/0xd0
    [<ffffffff8117cf2a>] __kmalloc+0x1ea/0x330
    [<ffffffffa04cafbb>] 0xffffffffa04cafbb
    [<ffffffffa04ad3a0>] 0xffffffffa04ad3a0
    [<ffffffffa04ae8fb>] 0xffffffffa04ae8fb
    [<ffffffffa0422e3a>] 0xffffffffa0422e3a
    [<ffffffffa0423022>] 0xffffffffa0423022
    [<ffffffff81096e86>] kthread+0x96/0xa0
    [<ffffffff8100c20a>] child_rip+0xa/0x20
    [<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Based on  my understanding, i did the following using gdb to find the function corresponding
but i get the following error

```
gdb resiter_access_i_o.ko
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-60.el6_4.1)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from resiter_access_i_o.ko ...done.
(gdb) info symbol 0xffffffffa04ae8fb
No symbol matches 0xffffffffa04ae8fb.
(gdb) q
```

Can some point me how to figure out the function corresponding to the above address? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I have seen such things when the allocation was made by a kernel module which had been unloaded after that. By the time kmemleak was printing the call trace, the module was unloaded and its symbol info was unknown. Assuming it was your module, you probably know the size of each section with the code in it, right? readelf may help. Then you may try to guess where the module was loaded (the start addresses of the areas for `.init.*` and `*.text*` are a multiple of 0x1000).

Comment: Or, you may try to analyze your module again but note the start addresses of its loaded sections before unloading it. See /sys/module/<module_name>/sections/<section name>. When you get the leak report from kmemleak then, you will be able to determine the sections where the functions were called and the offsets there. Then, `objdump -dr` or GDB could be used to find which functions were called.

Comment: One more opportunity is x86-only, but it seems the case for you. If the kernel is 2.6.32 or newer, you can use [memory leak detector](http://code.google.com/p/kedr/wiki/kedr_manual_getting_started) from [KEDR framework](http://code.google.com/p/kedr/). It determines the call stacks and the relevant addresses before the target module is completely unloaded and is therefore less affected by that problem.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for the replies. I will surely look at KEDR framework and post my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try tools like object dump, crashdum, crashtool, etc. 
you should easily be able to find the function name from these tools and the objects you have