# Using gdb to analyze kmemleak scan result

Tags: memory-leaks, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have read this link [Analyzing kmemleak result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657112/analyzing-kmemleak-result), but it seems not give the final answer.

After scanning the memory leak by kmemleak. I can derive the result of unreferenced object's address, say 0xffff880060bb3060 [in the update].

and I use the following gdb command to see the location of this address.
Note I found the .text_address in /sys/module/hello/session/.text, and the value is 0xffffffffa038c000

```
sudo insmod hello.ko        
gdb hello.ko /proc/kcore

add-symbol-file hello.ko 0xffffffffa038c000
list *0xffff880060bb3060
```

However the list command show nothing. 
I have used these steps to debug of kernel oops message, so I'm sure the command I type is correct.

So how can I use gdb to analyze the result given by kmemleak?

**Update**

I think I should also provide my sample code hello.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>


struct num {
    struct list_head node;
    int number;
};

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    LIST_HEAD(my_list);
    struct num *tmp;
    struct list_head *iterator;
    u8 i;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        tmp = kmalloc(sizeof(struct num), GFP_KERNEL); //I expect this line will be output as memory leak
        tmp->number = i;
        list_add(&tmp->node, &my_list);
    }

    list_for_each(iterator, &my_list) {
        printk("%d\n", list_entry(iterator, struct num, node)->number);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Good, haha\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

And the following is the scan result:

```
 unreferenced object 0xffff880060bb3060 (size 32):
      comm "swapper/0", pid 1, jiffies 4294895149 (age 802.568s)
      hex dump (first 32 bytes):
        00 01 10 00 00 00 ad de 00 02 20 00 00 00 ad de  .......... .....
        00 28 b1 57 00 88 ff ff 01 4f 0a 56 00 00 00 00  .(.W.....O.V....
      backtrace:
        [<ffffffff8170ea7e>] kmemleak_alloc+0x4e/0xc0
        [<ffffffff811a5de8>] kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xb8/0x160
        [<ffffffff810b0ed6>] pm_vt_switch_required+0x76/0xb0
        [<ffffffff813c1e61>] register_framebuffer+0x1d1/0x370
        [<ffffffff813db3fc>] vesafb_probe+0x5bc/0xa70
        [<ffffffff814870cc>] platform_drv_probe+0x3c/0x70
        [<ffffffff81484d74>] driver_probe_device+0x94/0x3d0
        [<ffffffff8148517b>] __driver_attach+0x8b/0x90
        [<ffffffff81482913>] bus_for_each_dev+0x73/0xb0
        [<ffffffff814847ae>] driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
        [<ffffffff814842f8>] bus_add_driver+0x208/0x2e0
        [<ffffffff81485844>] driver_register+0x64/0xf0
        [<ffffffff81486eca>] __platform_driver_register+0x4a/0x50
        [<ffffffff81d923f1>] vesafb_driver_init+0x12/0x14
        [<ffffffff810020f2>] do_one_initcall+0xf2/0x1b0
        [<ffffffff81d50f24>] kernel_init_freeable+0x144/0x1cc
```

Comment: Address of the leaked object doesn't correspond to any symbol - it is allocated memory, not a location in the code. You can use GDB(and other mechanisms) for resolve addresses in the backtrace, such as ffffffff810b0ed6, which corresponds to code of `pm_vt_switch_required` function.

Comment: the backtrace seems don't show the function like module_init or hello_init ? why? I mean the backtrace seems only show the kernel functions?

Comment: Because it is not a (direct) leak in you module. When leak corresponds to module, its name is appears in backtrace.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "not a direct leak" . I do one more experience, and the call trace like load_module->do_one_initcall, and it seems that hello_init is sent as a function pointer in do_one_initcall, so it actually call by the kernel function. That's why it not show in backtrace?

Comment: You just found a leak which is not related with your module at all. That's why your `hello_init` is not in the backtrace.